# Regex create a expression solving the following pattern

Tags: regex, formal-languages

This is part of a university optional homework and we are kinda struggling a bit.

The pattern to solve isn't that hard to be honest we don't get our heads around it,  create a expression that has the alphabet {a,b,c} contains at least one `a` and one `b`.

current two approaches are

`(a|b|c)*a(a|b|c)*b(a|b|c)* or (a|b|c)(a|b)(a|b|c)*(a|b)(a|b|c)*`

But both of these have flaws first one wouldnt allow ccbacc second one would allow ccaacc.

Greetings

Comment: Maybe use a *lookahead assertion* `(?=...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be two rules to produce the requirement, one is an `a` before a `b`:

```
S₁ → [abc]* a [abc]* b [abc]*
```

the other is a `b` before an `a`

```
S₂ → [abc]* b [abc]* a [abc]*
```

Now just combine them together using the alternative operator,

```
S → S₁ | S₂
  = [abc]* a [abc]* b [abc]* | [abc]* b [abc]* a [abc]*
```

This can be simplified using the rule `AB|AC = A(B|C)` and `AC|BC = (A|B)C`:

```
S → [abc]* (a [abc]* b | b [abc]* a) [abc]*
```

---

I assume your homework only deals with formal language. In real programming, just use `indexOf` or similar functions to find out if a string contains an `a` and a `b`. Regex is too heavy for this task.

Comment: Yep this was part of our Introduction lecutre for formal languages and we couldnt really get our heads around thanks very much for the explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

In complement of @kennytm's answer, some letters can be elided if you write the pattern in a way that targets the first occurrences of characters "a" and "b" (as opposed to *anywhere*). Obviously, the two approaches match exactly the same thing:

```
c*(a(a|c)*b|b(b|c)*a)(a|b|c)*
^   ^        ^---------------- only need "b" and "c" until the first "a"
|   '------------------------- only need "a" and "c" until the first "b"
'----------------------------- only need "c" until the first "a" or the first "b"
```

or using classes:

```
c*(a[ac]*b|b[bc]*a)[abc]*
```

Answer (score 2):

## Description

You'd really want to use lookahead assertions for this

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)[abc]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- ensure the the string only contains the letters `a`, `b`, and `c`
- requires the string to contain at least one `a`
- requires the string to contain at least one `b`

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/uK7hZ8/1

**Sample text**

```
dabc
fbca
cab
bac
acb
cba
```

**Sample Matches**

```
cab
bac
acb
cba
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    a                        'a'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    b                        'b'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [abc]*                   any character of: 'a', 'b', 'c' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thats a really nice explanation, going from a programmers PoV but we havent introduced most of these concepts yet, like the look ahead and going from the PoV of learning the answer given by @kennytm fits the purpose better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
/.*?((a.*?b)|(b.*?a)).*/
```

Comment: This matches strings outside the alphabet described, like `adb`.

Comment: Just need to replace dot with `[abc]`.  Don't forget to anchor the expression at the start and end

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead assertions for this:

```
(?=.*a)(?=.*b)
```

To return the characters in the match, you will need a non assertion match

```
[abc]*(?=.*a)(?=.*b)[abc]*
```

Comment: Won't a non-assertion match be required in this somewhere? Something like the class `[abc]`, so that `[abc]*(?=.*a)(?=.*b)[abc]*`?

Answer (score 0):

**First off** this is a text book problem best solved without regular expressions:

```
set(input) < set("ab")
```

Now, to take it for a spin, note the very **restricted alphabet**.

Thus, problem is equivalent to:

```
"acccccb" in input + reversed(input)
```

For arbitrary amount of repetition on `c`; Thus your expression becomes:

```
ac*b|bc*a
```

**Done**